# How to switch between screens / frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

My app is getting a bit big in size so I am trying to create sections like in the example image. When I click to general it will switch to general page, gonna switch to api for api page etc. I haven't used frames in my app at all.

Do I need to code everything from zero with frames to do this? Thanks.

[image: Example app sections]

Comment: What you can do is define a frame like ```Frame1=tk.Frame(your_master)``` and then ```Frame1.pack(fill="both",expand=1)```. And then change the widgets' master which are placed on the page.

Comment: There are many questions on this site that ask the same thing. Have you done any research before asking this question?

Comment: I know that you may be new person on SO, and I am giving you my upvote , although the question is unworthy. Please avoid asking such questions before a proper research because if all your questions would get downvotes like that, you will get a question ban, (which i have already.), so advising you to not do like me :), and for answer, you will need to write your code with including frames

Comment: I actually did a lot of research but couldn't find any useful information. Always asking as a last resort, thanks for the advices.

Comment: @Sujay I also didn't use pack, instead I did everything with grid so do I need to re do everything?

Comment: @JesJos, no, you just need to pack the frame. But you can use any geometry manager to place widgets inside the frame

Comment: @Sujay Getting this error: _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

Comment: ok, then try ```your_frame.place(x=0,y=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)``` where ```your_frame``` is the variable to which your ```Frame``` is assigned.

Comment: btw, it seems to me that You are using Menu for navigating frames, however usually the Menu is used similarly as You can use it in other apps like the browser (press Alt) and You can see the file, edite, view and other menus. For tabs it would probably be better to use something like `ttk.Notebook`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ttk.Notebook`, they have a `tabControl` modul.
You can use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqbkUKIc1Gk
Or read this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-tabbed-widget-with-python-tkinter/